# Casting when the reference type doesn't exist

Tags: java, casting

```
public class A {
}

public class B extends A {
}

public class C extends A {
}
public class D extends B {
}

public class E extends D {
}
```

The given hierarchy is like this.Questions are :

1- `A a = (D) new B();`

```
Runtime error (B cannot cast to D)
```

2- `A a = (D)((B)new E());`

```
No error
```

I do not understand why these situations occur , when we cast the concrete class and if there is no specific reference type of that class, how should we think ?

If these questions were like this , I could answer them:

```
B b = new B();
((D)b).someMethod();
```

It will give a `ClassCastException`.But I could not think like that in the above examples because there is no reference type. Thank you !

Comment: If you create a new object by e.g. calling `new B()`, this new object resides somewhere on the heap. You may not have a named reference to it, but an unnamed one (returned by the `new ...` call itself). This (unnamed) reference can be casted like any other.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Every type your example shows is a reference type. The reason you  cannot cast the reference expression `new B()` to type `D` is that `new B()` creates an object that is not of type `D`. Clearly. What is it that surprises you?

Answer (score 3):

Actually it's quite easy:

```
class Bird; 

class FlyingBird extends Bird;

class Eagle extends FlyingBird;

class Penguin extends Bird;
```

Something like

```
((Eagle)new Penguin()).fly();
```

Simply does not compute

Comment: I think that the actual semantics are clear to OP. What is confusing OP is the lack of a (named) reference to the object created by the call to `new ...` (before it gets casted).

Comment: Not sure if the OP asked for this, but this is a nice example :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider this:

[image]

you are saying:

```
 Animal x = (Turtle) new Dog();
```

just because

```
Animal x = new Dog();
```

and

```
Animal z = new Turtle();
```

does not mean a Turtle can be casted into a Dog or Dog into a Turtle, that is not how inheritance works if that were possible then you could cast a Turtle into a Dog and make it bark

Comment: I think that the actual semantics are clear to OP. What is confusing OP is the lack of a (named) reference to the object created by the call to `new ...` (before it gets casted).

Answer (score 0):

This situation in part 1 (direct cast fails, indirect cast succeeds) can occur when unboxing:

```
Number i = 123;               // Autoboxed
double d1 = (double)i;        // Runtime error
double d2 = (double)((int)i); // Works fine
```

Direct cast fails, because an `int` cannot be unboxed directly into a `double`.

However, indirect cast succeeds, because `i` can be unboxed into an `int`, and then `int` can be cast to `double`.